# Version control with delta processing uploads?

Tags: version-control, git, svn

I am planning to build a version control system to learn some advanced programming concepts in the process.

I've used git , perforce and svn.

I was wondering if any of them or other uses delta uploads and download like syncing only changes for individual files instead of entire files.

Comment: Mandatory comment: I don't think that it makes sense to implement your own version control system today. Seriously, if you do it correctly, you will end up with a design very similar to git. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @juhist there's quite a lot to be desired from git, such as sending and receiving only deltas on sync and file lock signalling for non-mergable binary files

Comment: What benefits would be obtained by having those additional features?

Comment: @RobertHarvey well transferring only deltas can reduce the bandwidth usage tremendously for large files that are updated frequently with small changes and an option to lock or flag a non mergable file would prevent people stepping on each others toes

Comment: Git is already pretty fast, and bandwidth is cheap.  I love the idea of a lock flag, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git compresses data into packfiles. So, even though in theory git is a storage mechanism for whole objects, in practice the objects are delta-compressed.

You can learn more about these packfiles from e.g. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles

The packing mechanism finds files that are similarly named in different versions, and have a size reasonably close to each other. It then concludes that these files are a good candidate for trying delta-compression, and the delta-compression is used if it had a measurable gain. If you change the entire contents of a file, git may conclude that delta-compression is not beneficial, and thus, the file is stored as-is. This differs significantly from older version control systems such as CVS (and perhaps SVN?) that always use delta-compression where the newest version of a file is stored as-is and the older versions are just the newest version minus deltas.

The delta-compression mechanism in git is able to utilize all CPU cores in the system by multithreading.

Comment: well yeah , and how about transferring those as deltas only too?

Comment: I think you'll find Git does that too: the packing mechanism is used not only for storage, but also for data transfers.